# Edit package version on gitlab with husky on merge request

Tags: git, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, husky

I want to edit my package version when I make a merge on Gitlab. I try with Husky like that but it's not working.

```
{
   "hooks":{
       "pre-commit": "npm run lint:fix",
      "post-merge": "(git-branch-is staging && npm version minor || git-branch-is master && npm version major) && git add . && git commit -m \"new version\"",
   }
}
```

And I try with Gitlab-CI like that

```
enable_merge:
  stage: staging_deploy
  only:
    - staging
  script:
    - npm version minor
```

And I get an error message

```
$ npm version minor
v0.5.0
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: git commit -m 0.5.0
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! *** Please tell me who you are.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run
npm ERR!
```

I can't do it on local because branches staging and master are protected

Answer (score 0):

Since this is running in CI, `git` likely doesn't have its config set up, especially with `user.name` and `user.email` which it uses for the author when you commit. I'd add these in a `before_script` step:

```yaml
enable_merge:
  stage: staging_deploy
  only:
    - staging
  before_script:
    - git config --global user.name "Gitlab CI"
    - git config --global user.email "an-email-address@example.com"
  script:
    - npm version minor
```